# What does an MKAnnotation and MKAnnotationView represent?

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, ipad

What does an MKAnnotation represent?  Is it like notes on the map - like if you open up google map and click on little icons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, an annotation is a pin/note/icon placed on the map (MKMapView) at a specific location.

MKAnnotation is the protocol your annotation object needs to implement defining its location and title.

MKAnnotationView represents the appearance of the annotation.  The view is requested by the MKMapView when your annotation object comes into the visible area.

See [MapKit Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008210) and the sample apps [MapCallouts](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746) and [WeatherMap](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009491).